# positioning of "a" when an object is long

Tags: determiners

For a description of a hotel offer, is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> This deal offers complimentary a Video On Demand ticket.

Comment: "A complimentary", not "complimentary a". I am migrating this to our sister site for English language learners.

Answer (score 3):

The noun in your sentence is *ticket*. The simplest version of the sentence, with the least information, is:

> This deal offers a ticket.

This begs the question: what kind of ticket? A plane ticket, a train ticket? What are we talking about here? So we add the adjective before the noun, but always after the *a*; the question is *"What kind of a ticket?"* Well, it's *a Video On Demand* one!

> This deal offers a Video On Demand ticket.

But you have an additional piece of information; the ticket is free! (Or as you wish to describe it, complimentary.) This is another adjective, which again we place before our current adjective/noun combination, but always after the *a*, because we're asking ourselves *"What kind of a *Video On Demand ticket?"* Well, *a complimentary one!*

> This deal offers a complimentary Video On Demand ticket.

Comment: Unless these *particular* tickets come from a company, promotional scheme, or whatever called **A Video On Demand**.

Answer (score 3):

The *determiner*, which may be

- an *article* ("a", "the")
- a *demonstrative* ("this", "that", "these", "yonder", &c)
- a *possessive* ("my", "his", "John's", &c)
- a *quantifier* ("one", "two", ... "all", "some", "any", "few",
  "many", "ever", and many more)

is always the **first** element in a noun phrase.

Consequently "complimentary a Video On Demand ticket" is ungrammatical; you must say:

> a complimentary Video On Demand ticket

Comment: While your answer is undoubtedly right in this case unfortunately it can't cope with examples like _too terrible a fate_.

Comment: @ColinFine In such cases the N' headed by the determiner is a component in a distinct "too X" or "so X" construction.

Answer (score 0):

The article goes before any adjective or attribute.

> This deal offers a complimentary "Video On Demand" ticket.

Similarly, when you say the quantity, that goes before adjectives and attributes.

> I saw two beautiful horses.

> I saw beautiful two horses. [This is wrong.]

Adjectives are generally written [following a particular order](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/order-adjectives), that is:

- General opinion
- Specific opinion
- Size
- Shape
- Age
- Colour
- Nationality
- Material

Comment: Determiner and quantifier phrases can be quite complex, and they precede adjectives. E.g, the bracketed part of _[Quite a few of the] loud abusive semi-drunken tourists left_ is a quantifier phrase, and all of it precedes all of those adjectives. That's why it's not a great idea to refer to articles and determiners and quantifiers as "adjectives"; yes, they modify nouns, but they don't behave like English attributive adjectives.

Comment: I didn't call the articles _adjectives_ (although the NOAD that I had in my previous OS X version called _the_ and _a_ adjectives, while now it says _determiner_). By _attibute_ I was referring to a noun preceding the word it qualifies.

Comment: Quite right, you didn't. _Attribute_ has several meanings.